# Optimizing multiplication of square matrices for full CPU utilization

Tags: optimization, c, matrix, sse, openmp

**Problem**

I am learning about HPC and code optimization. I attempt to replicate the results in [Goto's seminal matrix multiplication paper](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/pingali/CS378/2008sp/papers/gotoPaper.pdf). Despite my best efforts, I cannot get over ~50% maximum theoretical CPU performance.

**Background**

See related issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23790842/1157100), including info about my hardware.

**What I have attempted**

This related [paper](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/flame/pubs/blis3_ipdps14.pdf) has a good description of Goto's algorithmic structure. I provide my source code below.

**My question**

I am asking for general help. I have been working on this for far too long, have tried many different algorithms, inline assembly, inner kernels of various sizes (2x2, 4x4, 2x8, ..., mxn with m and n large), yet I cannot seem to break 50% CPU GFLOPS. This is purely for education purposes and not a homework.

**Compile Options**

On 32 bit GCC:

> gcc -std=c99 -O3 -msse3 -ffast-math -march=nocona -mtune=nocona -funroll-loops -fomit-frame-pointer -masm=intel

**Source Code**

I set up the macro structure (`for` loops) as described in the 2nd paper above. I pack the matrices as discussed in either paper. My inner kernel computes 2x8 blocks, as this seems to be the optimal computation for Nehalem architecture (see GotoBLAS source code - kernels). The inner kernel is based on the concept of calculating rank-1 updates as described [here](http://code.google.com/p/blis/source/browse/config/template/kernels/3/bli_gemm_opt_mxn.c).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdint.h>


// define some prefetch functions
#define PREFETCHNTA(addr,nrOfBytesAhead) \
        _mm_prefetch(((char *)(addr))+nrOfBytesAhead,_MM_HINT_NTA)

#define PREFETCHT0(addr,nrOfBytesAhead) \
        _mm_prefetch(((char *)(addr))+nrOfBytesAhead,_MM_HINT_T0)

#define PREFETCHT1(addr,nrOfBytesAhead) \
        _mm_prefetch(((char *)(addr))+nrOfBytesAhead,_MM_HINT_T1)

#define PREFETCHT2(addr,nrOfBytesAhead) \
        _mm_prefetch(((char *)(addr))+nrOfBytesAhead,_MM_HINT_T2)

// define a min function
#ifndef min
    #define min( a, b ) ( ((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b) )
#endif

// zero a matrix
void zeromat(double *C, int n)
{
    int i = n;
    while (i--) {
        int j = n;
        while (j--) {
            *(C + i*n + j) = 0.0;
        }
    }
}

// compute a 2x8 block from (2 x kc) x (kc x 8) matrices
inline void 
__attribute__ ((gnu_inline))        
__attribute__ ((aligned(64))) dgemm_2x8_sse(
                int k,
                const double* restrict a1, const int cs_a,
                const double* restrict b1, const int rs_b,
                      double* restrict c11, const int rs_c
                )
{

    register __m128d xmm1, xmm4, //
                    r8, r9, r10, r11, r12, r13, r14, r15; // accumulators

    // 10 registers declared here

    r8 = _mm_xor_pd(r8,r8); // ab
    r9 = _mm_xor_pd(r9,r9);
    r10 = _mm_xor_pd(r10,r10);
    r11 = _mm_xor_pd(r11,r11);

    r12 = _mm_xor_pd(r12,r12); // ab + 8
    r13 = _mm_xor_pd(r13,r13);
    r14 = _mm_xor_pd(r14,r14);
    r15 = _mm_xor_pd(r15,r15);

        // PREFETCHT2(b1,0);
        // PREFETCHT2(b1,64);



    //int l = k;
    while (k--) {

        //PREFETCHT0(a1,0); // fetch 64 bytes from a1

            // i = 0
            xmm1 = _mm_load1_pd(a1);

            xmm4 = _mm_load_pd(b1);
            xmm4 = _mm_mul_pd(xmm1,xmm4);
            r8 = _mm_add_pd(r8,xmm4);

            xmm4 = _mm_load_pd(b1 + 2);
            xmm4 = _mm_mul_pd(xmm1,xmm4);
            r9 = _mm_add_pd(r9,xmm4);

            xmm4 = _mm_load_pd(b1 + 4);
            xmm4 = _mm_mul_pd(xmm1,xmm4);
            r10 = _mm_add_pd(r10,xmm4);

            xmm4 = _mm_load_pd(b1 + 6);
            xmm4 = _mm_mul_pd(xmm1,xmm4);
            r11 = _mm_add_pd(r11,xmm4);

            //
            // i = 1
            xmm1 = _mm_load1_pd(a1 + 1);

            xmm4 = _mm_load_pd(b1);
            xmm4 = _mm_mul_pd(xmm1,xmm4);
            r12 = _mm_add_pd(r12,xmm4);

            xmm4 = _mm_load_pd(b1 + 2);
            xmm4 = _mm_mul_pd(xmm1,xmm4);
            r13 = _mm_add_pd(r13,xmm4);

            xmm4 = _mm_load_pd(b1 + 4);
            xmm4 = _mm_mul_pd(xmm1,xmm4);
            r14 = _mm_add_pd(r14,xmm4);

            xmm4 = _mm_load_pd(b1 + 6);
            xmm4 = _mm_mul_pd(xmm1,xmm4);
            r15 = _mm_add_pd(r15,xmm4);

        a1 += cs_a;
        b1 += rs_b;

        //PREFETCHT2(b1,0);
        //PREFETCHT2(b1,64);

    }

        // copy result into C

        PREFETCHT0(c11,0);
        xmm1 = _mm_load_pd(c11);
        xmm1 = _mm_add_pd(xmm1,r8);
        _mm_store_pd(c11,xmm1);

        xmm1 = _mm_load_pd(c11 + 2);
        xmm1 = _mm_add_pd(xmm1,r9);
        _mm_store_pd(c11 + 2,xmm1);

        xmm1 = _mm_load_pd(c11 + 4);
        xmm1 = _mm_add_pd(xmm1,r10);
        _mm_store_pd(c11 + 4,xmm1);

        xmm1 = _mm_load_pd(c11 + 6);
        xmm1 = _mm_add_pd(xmm1,r11);
        _mm_store_pd(c11 + 6,xmm1);

        c11 += rs_c;

        PREFETCHT0(c11,0);
        xmm1 = _mm_load_pd(c11);
        xmm1 = _mm_add_pd(xmm1,r12);
        _mm_store_pd(c11,xmm1);

        xmm1 = _mm_load_pd(c11 + 2);
        xmm1 = _mm_add_pd(xmm1,r13);
        _mm_store_pd(c11 + 2,xmm1);

        xmm1 = _mm_load_pd(c11 + 4);
        xmm1 = _mm_add_pd(xmm1,r14);
        _mm_store_pd(c11 + 4,xmm1);

        xmm1 = _mm_load_pd(c11 + 6);
        xmm1 = _mm_add_pd(xmm1,r15);
        _mm_store_pd(c11 + 6,xmm1);

}

// packs a matrix into rows of slivers
inline void 
__attribute__ ((gnu_inline))        
__attribute__ ((aligned(64))) rpack(        double* restrict dst, 
          const double* restrict src, 
            const int kc, const int mc, const int mr, const int n)
{
    double tmp[mc*kc] __attribute__ ((aligned(64)));
    double* restrict ptr = &tmp[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < mc; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < kc; ++j)
            *ptr++ = *(src + i*n + j);

    ptr = &tmp[0];

    //const int inc_dst = mr*kc;
    for (int k = 0; k < mc; k+=mr)
        for (int j = 0; j < kc; ++j)
            for (int i = 0; i < mr*kc; i+=kc)
                *dst++ = *(ptr + k*kc + j + i);

}

// packs a matrix into columns of slivers
inline void 
__attribute__ ((gnu_inline))        
__attribute__ ((aligned(64)))  cpack(double* restrict dst, 
                const double* restrict src, 
                const int nc, 
                const int kc, 
                const int nr, 
                const int n)
{
    double tmp[kc*nc] __attribute__ ((aligned(64)));
    double* restrict ptr = &tmp[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < kc; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < nc; ++j)
            *ptr++ = *(src + i*n + j);

    ptr = &tmp[0];

    // const int inc_k = nc/nr;
    for (int k = 0; k < nc; k+=nr)
        for (int j = 0; j < kc*nc; j+=nc)
            for (int i = 0; i < nr; ++i)
                *dst++ = *(ptr + k + i + j);

}

void blis_dgemm_ref(
        const int n,
        const double* restrict A,
        const double* restrict B,
        double* restrict C,
        const int mc,
        const int nc,
        const int kc
    )
{
    int mr = 2;
    int nr = 8;
    double locA[mc*kc] __attribute__ ((aligned(64)));
    double locB[kc*nc] __attribute__ ((aligned(64)));
    int ii,jj,kk,i,j;
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4) shared(A,B,C) private(ii,jj,kk,i,j,locA,locB)
    {//use all threads in parallel
        #pragma omp for
        // partitions C and B into wide column panels
        for ( jj = 0; jj < n; jj+=nc) {
        // A and the current column of B are partitioned into col and row panels
            for ( kk = 0; kk < n; kk+=kc) {
                cpack(locB, B + kk*n + jj, nc, kc, nr, n);
                // partition current panel of A into blocks
                for ( ii = 0; ii < n; ii+=mc) {
                    rpack(locA, A + ii*n + kk, kc, mc, mr, n);
                    for ( i = 0; i < min(n-ii,mc); i+=mr) {
                        for ( j = 0; j < min(n-jj,nc); j+=nr) {
                            // inner kernel that compues 2 x 8 block
                            dgemm_2x8_sse( kc,
                                       locA + i*kc          ,  mr,
                                       locB + j*kc          ,  nr,
                                       C + (i+ii)*n + (j+jj),  n );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

double compute_gflops(const double time, const int n)
{
    // computes the gigaflops for a square matrix-matrix multiplication
    double gflops;
    gflops = (double) (2.0*n*n*n)/time/1.0e9;
    return(gflops);
}

// ******* MAIN ********//
void main() {
    clock_t time1, time2;
    double time3;
    double gflops;
    const int trials = 10;

    int nmax = 4096;
    printf("%10s %10s\n","N","Gflops/s");

    int mc = 128;
    int kc = 256;
    int nc = 128;

    for (int n = kc; n <= nmax; n+=kc) { //assuming kc is the max dim
        double *A = NULL;
        double *B = NULL;
        double *C = NULL;

        A = _mm_malloc (n*n * sizeof(*A),64);
        B = _mm_malloc (n*n * sizeof(*B),64);
        C = _mm_malloc (n*n * sizeof(*C),64);

        srand(time(NULL));

        // Create the matrices
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                A[i*n + j] = (double) rand()/RAND_MAX;
                B[i*n + j] = (double) rand()/RAND_MAX;
                //D[j*n + i] = B[i*n + j]; // Transpose
                C[i*n + j] = 0.0;
            }
        }

            // warmup
            zeromat(C,n);
            blis_dgemm_ref(n,A,B,C,mc,nc,kc);
            zeromat(C,n);
            time2 = 0;
            for (int count = 0; count < trials; count++){// iterations per experiment here
                    time1 = clock();
                    blis_dgemm_ref(n,A,B,C,mc,nc,kc);
                    time2 += clock() - time1;
                    zeromat(C,n);
                }
            time3 = (double)(time2)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC/trials;
            gflops = compute_gflops(time3, n);
            printf("%10d %10f\n",n,gflops);

        _mm_free(A);
        _mm_free(B);
        _mm_free(C);

        }

    printf("tests are done\n");
}
```

Comment: What is your physical hardware...? 4-core with HT?

Comment: i5 540M. 2 cores with HT turned off. More details here: http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Core_i5/Intel-Core%20i5%20Mobile%20I5-540M%20CP80617004116AD%20%28BX80617I5540M%29.html

Answer (score 6):

Without addressing performance concerns, some trivial observations:

- `#include <omp.h>` is unnecessary.  (You use OpenMP, but don't call any OpenMP functions.)
- The [return type of `main()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/1157100) should be `int`, not `void`.
- The code also compiles with `clang` (LLVM), if you omit the `-masm=intel` option.
- `zeromat()` could simply be `memset(C, 0, n * sizeof(double))`.
- When compiling with `-Wall`, the code in `dgemm_2x8_sse()` to zero some registers causes spurious warnings:

  > ```
  > matmul.c:56:21: warning: variable 'r8' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
  >     r8 = _mm_xor_pd(r8,r8); // ab
  >                     ^~
  > matmul.c:52:5: note: variable 'r8' is declared here
  >     register __m128d xmm1, xmm4, //
  >     ^
  > ```

  I recommend disabling the warnings with a pair of pragmas:

  ```
  #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wuninitialized"
      r8 = _mm_xor_pd(r8,r8); // ab
      r9 = _mm_xor_pd(r9,r9);
      r10 = _mm_xor_pd(r10,r10);
      r11 = _mm_xor_pd(r11,r11);

      r12 = _mm_xor_pd(r12,r12); // ab + 8
      r13 = _mm_xor_pd(r13,r13);
      r14 = _mm_xor_pd(r14,r14);
      r15 = _mm_xor_pd(r15,r15);
  #pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wuninitialized"
  ```

  You should also discard the confusing and useless comment that precedes that code:

  ```
  // 10 registers declared here
  ```
- "Gflops/s" is redundant and incorrect terminology (unless you are talking about acceleration, not [speed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOPS)!)

Comment: Regarding compiler flags, I'd argue that `-march=nocona -mtune=nocona` and probably `-msse3` too, unless you want to force GCC to use nothing newer, are redundant.
`march` will generate code optimized only for that CPU, while `mtune` for that CPU and its family. 
[Moreover, specifying -march=cpu-type implies -mtune=cpu-type.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.3/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html).
And `march` will take also care of `sse`.

Comment: The warning on `r8` is interesting, I wonder what causes it. **EDIT** The comment about the registers was actually important but unclear. I coded my `dgemm_2x8_sse()` directly in assembly (inline gcc assembly, intel syntax). I thought I would be able to use 16 `xmm` registers, but apparently I can only access 8. So my little note was to inform me of how many registers I declared in the `C` code. I was unable to reduce it to 8, so I could not code it as efficiently as I hoped in assembly.

Comment: Getting compilers to do things that don't depend on the input is tricky.  Older gcc will often zero out variables before you use them for something like `_mm_cmpeq_si128(x,x)` to generate all-ones.  Instead, use `_mm_setzero_pd()` to generate a zeroing `xorpd` or equivalent with the compiler's choice of register.  Similarly, you actually get better code from `_mm_set1_epi32(-1)` than from trying to do it directly with `v=_mm_uninitialized_si128(); ones = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(v,v);`  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/32422471/224132 and the comments

Comment: @black: `-march=native` doesn't fully imply `-mtune=native`, unfortunately.  I can't find an example right now, but yesterday I was looking at g++ output that didn't put `cmp/jcc` next to each other with `-march=native`, but it did with `-march=native -mtune=native`.  (On godbolt, where native=haswell).

Comment: @user43443: No, the warning on `r8` is the same you'd get if you did `int a; int b = 2*a;`.  The compiler doesn't warn you if it has to spill registers to the stack.  Use 64bit; the 32bit ABI is obsolete, and passes float/double on the stack, and returns them in x87 registers.  Also, as you saw, you only get 8 registers in 32bit mode, regardless of ABI.  (No REX prefix to give an extra bit to select the other 8 src/dest registers.)